# corrupted library (?) preventing ipad upload to icloud photos

Tags: ipad, icloud, photos

My ipad was not downloading photos from icloud photos, and was stuck uploading xxx photos. I tried turning icloud photos (and photo stream etc) on and off, and restarting the ipad, with no change in behavior. I then turned off icloud photos, deleted every photo off the ipad, turned it on and noticed that now, it says it is uploading 5 photos. These photos appear to not exist (the library is empty, the deleted files album is empty, and i have removed all albums, and are not visible either using image capture or windows) and I presume this is the source of my sync problems.

I then backed up the ipad, and restored from backup, and the problem persists.

I have one thing left to try that I can think of - restore as new and re-install from scratch - but this will be painful. Can anyone suggest an alternative?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 1):

I can only tell you that I have the same problem, but on my iPhone. The only time I get it to work is when I turn iCloud entirely on and off. Yet – after a successful sync with all images and videos everywhere, the sync problem reemerge. Your mileage may vary. Try a complete iCloud off/on (and – I would recommend – a reboot in between) and see what happens.